# How to manage different versions of R on Mac?

Tags: macos, r, versioning, rstudio

I use R with RStudio on the Mac. In order to use different packages I need to use several versions of R. It seems that [RSwitch](http://r.research.att.com/) is no longer available for download. How do I manage different versions of R in the easiest way on the Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was asked and [answered today on the R_SIG_Mac mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2012-November/009713.html). It appears that the maintainer of that tool had some HD issues and some of his copies of those files were lost, leading to a bunch of dead links on the site.

Some other R core members have [working links to the dmg](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/R/) that you can find at the link above.

That was actually a temporary problem and as of early 2015 the current and prior versions of Rswitch can be found at: http://r.research.att.com/